# Picker View displaces objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm making an app with a picker view, and when a button is pressed, the picker view pops up, and when another button is pressed, it disappears. In the storyboard, the picker view covers the bottom half of the screen, including two buttons, but when I run the simulator, the buttons and other objects that are on the screen (such as labels and text fields) get shifted to seemingly random places, including the objects that are not covered by the picker view. What exactly is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific ? Maybe it is related to auto-layout option. Try to deactivate it from storyboard.

Comment: The problem that you are having is cause by Auto Layout. Disable it if you don't want it. You can disable it in IB by selecting the VC, going to the File Inspector and unchecking the "Use Autolayout" box.

Comment: What do I do for the iPhone 5 then? When I set the picker to the bottom in the iPhone 4 storyboard, and then change it the iPhone 5 length, the picker gets stuck in the middle of the screen. Edit: Never mind, I figured it out in the size inspector

Answer (score 0):

Go to the story board, select that particular view controller on which you have placed the picker view and open document outline window(which appear on the left side of story board). After that you will get the list of components present on that view. Drag the labels and the buttons to the bottom of the picker view. By doing this you will get the labels and the buttons on the top of the picker view and add the constraints to the components.
Another reason might be that you have selected other model at the bottom and ran on other model.
Just set the constraints it will solve the problems. And delete suggested constraints.